# Why this output is 0%?

Tags: c++, types

This program is going to calculate the ratio. The correct output should be 4.50492%, but my output is 0%. I doubt it's the size problem. However, the size of double is 8 bytes, and so type long long is. What's wrong with my program? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    //cout << "Enter the world's population: ";
    long long world = 6898758899;
    //cin >> world;
    //cout << "Enter the population of US: ";
    long long us = 310783781;
    //cin >> us;

    double ratio = us/world * 100;
    char percentage = '%';
    cout << "The population of the US is " << ratio << percentage << " of the world population." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're diving integers so it becomes 0 (as decimal places are truncated). Make one operand double.

Comment: Try `double ratio = static_cast<double>(us)/world * 100;`.

Comment: This happens because division is done after multiplication. By the time the division is done, the result is already zero, so zero times 100 is still zero.

Comment: You mean the result of us/world is 0, right? However, I try to use double(us/world), but the output is also 0%. @AndrewLi

Comment: @C.Charles Well yes it would be. Division is performed **first**, then you promote to double. Cast one of the operands to a double *before* the operation.

Comment: I see. So I use double(us)/world is OK. THANK YOU!!!!! @AndrewLi

Answer (score 1):

because "us" and "world" type is long long.So "us/world" is long long.(long)0.0450492 == 0.

the correct spelling is

```
double ratio = (double)us/(double)world * 100.0;
```

Comment: Only one operand needs to be double.